# How to query an object with a specific key/value pair in an array with Mongodb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

This is my data structure:

```
{
  studentName: 'zzz',
  teachers: [
    {
      teacherName: 'xxx',
      feedbacks: []
    }, {
      teacherName: 'yyy',
      feedbacks: []
    }
  ]
}
```

Now I am trying to code a query to add an 'feedback' object to the 'feedbacks' array that belongs to the teacher named 'yyy'.

```
await collection.updateOne({
                studentName: 'zzz',
                teachers: {
                    $elemMatch: {
                        teacherName: {
                            $eq: 'yyy'
                        }
                    }
                }
            }, {
                $push: {
                    'teachers.$.feedbacks': {}
                }
            })
```

The query part is faulty somehow. If I change '$' to 0 or 1, then the code works finally. Otherwise, the object cannot be pushed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This update works fine, adds the string element "Nice work" to the `teachers.feedbacks` nested array.

```
db.test.updateOne(
  {
     studentName: "zzz",
     "teachers.teacherName": "yyy"
   },
   { $push: { "teachers.$.feedbacks" : "Nice work" } }
)
```

The `$elemMatch` syntax is not required, as the query condition for the array elements is for a single field.

The updated document:

```
{
        "studentName" : "zzz",
        "teachers" : [
                {
                        "teacherName" : "xxx",
                        "feedbacks" : [ ]
                },
                {
                        "teacherName" : "yyy",
                        "feedbacks" : [
                                "Nice work"
                        ]
                }
        ]
}
```

Comment: As 'teachers' is an array, there should be something in between, shouldn't there? Like 'teacher.something.teacherName'.

Comment: In JS, `teachers.forEach(x => if (x.teacherName == 'yyy'){do something})`. In this case 'x' is the intermediary, so MongoDB is a different story, isn't it? I did as you said,and it works, but I'm still confused.

Comment: _there should be something in between, shouldn't there? Like 'teacher.something.teacherName'_ No, it is not required, in this case.